# Splitting DateTime into two columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a datetime field (e.g. 2013-07-02 01:14:32.000) that I'm trying to split into two columns with the Alias Column name of "Date Added" and "Time Added:".  I would only like to see the results of all the data that consists in the 4 day span prior to the current date.  I would also like to cut out the microseconds.  Is this an easy fix or not?  I'm still learning the ropes of SQL Server Management Studio 2008.  Can anyone edit my query to display the correct output?

### Existing Query:

```
  Select as_key AS [Key:], as_name AS [Server Name:], as_introdate AS [Date Added:]
  from AutomationStations
  Order By [Date Added:] desc
```

### Sample Output from Existing Query:

```
  Key: 0001
  Server Name: Server1
  Date Added: 2013-07-02 01:14:32.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way it to extract the desired parts from [built-in date formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    as_key AS [Key:], 
    as_name AS [Server Name:],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),as_introdate,101) AS [Date Added:],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) ,as_introdate,108) AS [Time Added:]
FROM AutomationStations
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,as_introdate,GETDATE()) <= 4
ORDER BY as_introdate DESC
```

Comment: it is giving me this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Comment: I missed a comma after the first CONVERT.  See my updated answer.

Comment: and also would this filter it to the last 4 days as well?

Comment: how would I add that filter to your suggested query?

Comment: Added a WHERE clause.  note that `DATEDIFF` does NOT include the current day, so you may need to adjust the filter accordingly

Comment: DATEDIFF(d,as_introdate,GETDATE()) <= 4 is extremely slow. You are comparing a computed value for all rows

Comment: "Extremely slow" may be strong - unless there are MANY rows in the table, the difference is probably not noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Or an alternate method casting to Date and Time datatypes..

```
SELECT 
    as_key AS 'Key:', 
    as_name AS 'Server Name:',
    CAST(as_introdate AS DATE) 'Date Added:',
    CAST(as_introdate AS TIME(0)) AS 'Time Added:' 
FROM AutomationStations
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,as_introdate,GETDATE()) <= 4
ORDER BY as_introdate DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CONVERT(DATE, YOUR_SELECTED_DATETIME) AS DATE,
CONVERT(TIME, YOUR_SELECTED_DATETIME) AS TIME
```

This way you keep your data types.